# What alternatives are there to using an object of a contravariant interface polymorphously?

Tags: c#, abstraction, generics, factory

The gist of what I'm trying to do is get an instance of the appropriate user service, then pass it whatever subtype of `User` we're working with.

**Models:**

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : User
{
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Staff : User
{
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Services:**

```
public interface IUserService<T> where T : User
{
    void Save(T user);
}

public class StudentService : IUserService<Student>
{
    public void Save(Student user)
    {
        // Student-specific code
    }
}

public class StaffService : IUserService<Staff>
{
    public void Save(Staff user)
    {
        // Staff-specific code
    }
}
```

My first try was to new up the matching service and up-cast. I found out that didn't work since it would violate type safety: e.g., the compiler wouldn't be able to tell if I were passing in a compatible user later on.

```
public void Process(User user)
{
    IUserService<User> service;

    if (user is Staff)
        service = (IUserService<User>)new StaffService(); // InvalidCastException
    else if (user is Student)
        service = (IUserService<User>)new StudentService(); // InvalidCastException
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("...");

    service.Save(user);
}
```

I understand why that's the case now, but I haven't been able to come up with an alternative that still allows for:

1. Enforcing a contract (any user service has to implement these methods)
2. Calling methods in a generic way (just pass in the user object)
3. Avoiding duplicate code

What I really don't want to do is end up with something like:

```
if (user is Staff)
{
    var service = new StaffService();
    service.Save(user);
}
else if (user is Student)
{
    var service = new StudentService();
    service.Save(user);
}
// etc.
```

Not so bad with two user types and one method call, but the actual code is more complex.

Comment: Isn't this a need for Dependency Injection?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423125/polymorphism-and-interfaces-in-java-can-polymorphism-be-used-to-implement-inter

Comment: If you have a stable set of user subclasses, a visitor would be reasonable. You could then write an IUserService on User that stores a IUserService for each subtype and uses the visitor interface to dispatch the appropriate service.

Comment: why not `void process<T> where T : User` ?

Comment: @Caleth Exactly what I ended up changing it to. Kicking myself for missing it, but a good night's rest does wonders. Could you repost as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match the UserService subtype to the User subtype, which is fairly simple to do with (the same) type parameter you use in IUserService.

```
public void Process<T>(T user) where T : User
{
    IUserService<T> service;

    if (user is Staff)
        service = new StaffService(); // No more cast
    else if (user is Student)
        service = new StudentService(); // No more cast
    else
        throw new ArgumentException("...");

    service.Save(user);
}
```

This still has the problem that Process has to know what Service class to instantiate, which we can get around slightly awkwardly like so:

```
public void Process<T, S>(T user) where T : User where S : IUserService<T>
{
    IUserService<T> service = new S(); // No more "if ... is ..." chain   
    service.Save(user);
}
```

However that will complicate the call sites of Process

Comment: I don't think that first code snippet will compile. C# doesn't take into account the `user is Staff` when checking if it can assign a `StaffService` to `service`

Comment: The whole point is that service is IUserService<Staff> because of the generic parameter

Comment: This did it! Thanks. I ended up moving the instantiation into a factory and kept just the one type parameter. Works great.

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, but the compiler will want every branch to be valid for all possible `T`. It doesn't take into account that some branches will only be run for some values of `T`. It doesn't say "well we only try to assign `StaffService` if `T` is `Staff` so we only need to assign a `StaffService` to `IUserService<Staff>`". Try copy-pasting it into Visual Studio and you'll see.